# Java Filter and count of calls

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have written test Filter (javax.servlet.Filter) and started to debug. And I was surprised that one refresh of html page calls twice method doFilter().
Could anybody describe me why it happens ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your filter was called also for static elements (images, etc.). Check your filter path declaration in `web.xml`.

One way to check what's really happening is to use either [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Or both.

Another strategy to use is printing value of `request.getRequestURL().toString()` before `doFilter()`, so you can see what requests are being served. It's difficult to pinpoint why are you seeing 2 requests because the cause might be hidden somewhere in your environment or configuration.

Comment: I have simple html page without any elements, But filter for all elements I mean URL PATTERN IS <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>.

Comment: Page is: <html>
  <head><title>Test jsp</title></head>
  <body>Test content</body>
</html>

Comment: Yes you was right it was calls to the favicon.ico,  but my html page does not have this icon ...

Answer (score 1):

Fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) and watch the requests being made.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it.